# Play ! 2.1: Minifying CSS, not LESS

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm having trouble with the CSS minification feature provided in Play Framework 2.1.
I know it works good with .less files, but I'm interested in minifying plain old css files.

I was researching possible solutions and writing a custom assets compiler using YUICompressor looks like a nice solution. But I couldn't find a good resource how to write one and plug it in to Play so he could pick them up and "compile" them.

Also I would like to ask if Play has some build'in functionality to switch those scripts while going into production mode.

Comment: One way of making use of the provided less compiler is to just rename the `.css` files to `.less` files but still keep the plain css code in the files. It will work fine and you will get minified css files. I haven't checked but it might be possible to instruct the `lessEntryPoints` to consider `.css` files as well. But the renaming of file extensions should work well at least.

Comment: I've tried that, and the provided CSS keep crashing the LESS compiler with error "char at 0" or something simillar. I don't want to use LESS at all.

Answer (score 0):

I started to build a plugin for Play, which will do that what I require.
Will post it here when it will get to a usable state